# Redirecting to a show, but unable to find id parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a party planning app for practice and have run into some trouble. I need to be able to show my specific party when clicked on, but it does not seem to work. I get this error:

undefined method `show_party_path' for #<#:0x007fb115660620>

I have defined a show method in the parties controller like this:

```
def show
    @party = Party.find(params[:id])
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <% @parties.each do |party| %>
        <tr>
          <td><p><%= link_to party.title, show_party_path(@party) %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.start_time %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.end_time %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.address %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.city %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.state %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.zipcode %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.phone %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.email %></p></td>
          <td><p><%= party.url %></p></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Remove", party, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <%= link_to "New Party", new_party_path %>
```

Interstingly, when I click on the show, it also has a strange url. It goes from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/parties. It does not specify an actual party id. With no input parameters, how would the show know which party to show?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
   parties GET    /parties(.:format)          parties#index
           POST   /parties(.:format)          parties#create
 new_party GET    /parties/new(.:format)      parties#new
edit_party GET    /parties/:id/edit(.:format) parties#edit
     party GET    /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#show
           PATCH  /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#update
           PUT    /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#update
           DELETE /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#destroy
      root GET    /                           parties#index
```

Best, 
Eric

Comment: use `rake routes` to show your available paths. The `show` party path looks like `party_path(@party)` by default.

Comment: If the format in the rake routes is party  GET    /parties/:id(.:format)      parties#show does that mean show need a url with localhost:3000/parties/party_id? How do I change the url to include the party_id?

Comment: As ForgetTheNorm suggested: `party_path(@party)` will add the id to the url

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some additional details and context to further answer your question.

Presuming, based on the result of `rake routes`, that your `config/routes.rb` file has this in it:

```
resources :parties
```

Then, for free, you get seven different routes auto-generated for you, all of which relate to RESTful CRUD operations.  The one in question here, of course, is Read, and by declaring the line above, in the background, you get:

```
get '/parties/:id', to: 'parties#show', as: 'parties'
```

Now, normal logic for other methods would indeed say use `show_party_path`, but this is a special case since you are using resourceful routing.  The "show" part has apparently been deemed superfluous.

So, instead, simply change your `link_to` call to:

```
link_to @party.title, party_path(@party)
```

Passing `@party` is essentially passing `@party.id` as the parameter.

Pro tip:  You can also do this:

```
link_to @party.title, @party
```

To achieve the same effect.

I would *definitely* advise against editing your routes config to force support for `show_party_path`, as that will be inconsistent with any other routing you do and unnecessarily go against norms and practices.  Generally speaking, Rails is easy to work with within the confines of its rules -- and the opposite is just as true.

For more details on Routing, check out:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

looks like you left something out of your route declaration..

```
get "/parties/:id", to: "parties#show", as: "show_party"
```

I *think* that is what you are after.